# Making a Salt `onchanges` requisite dependent on what has changed

Tags: salt-stack

I want to execute a Salt state not always when changes happened in another state, but only for specific changes. This appears like I would have to make `onchanges`/`onchanges_in` dependent on the specific changes.

[The respective bug report](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/883) has been closed saying "this is totally resolved now that states have access to the running dict and the lowstate for a state run". However, I can find no documentation on that and hardly any explanation of what the "running dict" actually is.

So I guess the question could also be rephrased as "How do I access the 'running dict' in an `onchanges` requisite?", but I'm open to any solutions for the original problem. Thanks for your help!

---

**Update:** A comment asked for a specific example, so here is my use case: As most state modules, [`user.present`](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.user.html#salt.states.user.present) may either update fields of an existing (user) object or create a new one. Then, I want to run a second state module if and only if a specific field has been changed and/or the object has just been created. In Ansible, for comparison, I would [`register` a variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#registered-variables) and access the module's result through it.

So, why would I want to do that?

Essentially, I want to create user accounts on Linux and have them be able to set their own password (when logged in via an SSH key). `user.present` supports `empty_password` for that purpose, but it doesn't play nicely with `enforce_password`. This means that after a password has been manually set, a repeated state run will clear that password again. One might even consider this a bug in Salt, but the interactions between the different `user.present` fields are convoluted and debatable.

My solution is to create the accounts first and run a `module.run` state executing [`shadow.del_password`](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.shadow.html#salt.modules.shadow.del_password) afterwards. This is realised through an `onchanges_in` requisite. However, password deletion should not be triggered for any change, but only when the user account is created, which is also the only case my `user.present` state touches the password at all. Otherwise, things like adding users to a group would clear their password. For that effect, I think I would have to look into the details of the `user.present` change.

```
Create user account for dummy:
  user.present:
    - name: dummy
    - gid_from_name: True
    - remove_groups: False
    # TODO: This should be made more specific
    - onchanges_in:
      - module: Allow dummy to set a password

Allow dummy to set a password:
  module.run:
    - name: shadow.del_password
    - m_name: dummy
    # Make sure that this is not executed accidentally if no `onchanges_in` is present
    - onchanges: []
    - require:
      - user: Create user account for dummy
```

Comment: Please make this question more specific by writing about the problem you want to solve (what kind of change, what kind of action?)

Comment: @ahus1 I have added a detailed use case example.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about specific onchanges or the 'running dict', but, for your particular use case, you can use a condition to enable your password clearing state only when needed, such as:

```
Create user account for dummy:
  user.present:
    - name: dummy
    - gid_from_name: True
    - remove_groups: False

{% if salt['user.info']('dummy') == {} %}
# Only clear the password if the account didn't exist before
Allow dummy to set a password:
  module.run:
    - name: shadow.del_password
    - m_name: dummy
    - require:
      - user: Create user account for dummy
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This feels a bit hacky and can't be fully generalized, but I guess it's the nicest known solution for the specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to use in this case is `module.wait`, not `module.run`. `module.wait` by default will not do anything, unless asked by something else. Also, `onchanges_in` for some reason (I think [this issue](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/19592)) doesn't play well with `module.wait` for me. I've tried `watch_in` and it did the job.

I've tried the following code and it seem to work just fine. It creates a user with an empty password and doesn't change anything if user is already there:

```
Create user account for dummy:
  user.present:
    - name: dummy
    - gid_from_name: True
    - remove_groups: False
    # TODO: This should be made more specific
    - watch_in:
      - module: Allow dummy to set a password

Allow dummy to set a password:
  module.wait:
    - name: shadow.del_password
    - m_name: dummy
    - require:
      - user: Create user account for dummy
```

Comment: This still has the problem that `shadow.del_password` gets executed every time there is any change to the user account, e.g. adding it to a group (admittedly not in my minimal example, but in the actual code).

Comment: Concerning `onchanges` and `run` vs. `watch` and `wait`, there is a [statement by a Salt developer](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/29492#issuecomment-162967147) from 2015 which announces `wait` states to be deprecated. (Preceded by [this mailing list thread](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/salt-users/152q47sx85/should-wait-sates-be-deprecated-in-favor-of-onchanges).)

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I misread your question. In this case I think it's either what @christophe-drevet-droguet suggested or writing a python state.